# mod_rewrite rule for pdf files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To get a balance between browser-cache and ensuring up-to-date content I'm generating a directory listing with fake directories based mtime() of the pdf.

```
/523523624/aboutus.pdf
/236342346/our_bikes.pdf
```

the numeric directories doesn't exists, the list is generated by PHP, looking at the modification time of the pdf-file.

Now, I need mod_rewrite to discard the /[0-9]/ directory and serve the freshly baked pdf to the browser.

Please help out with an apache rule. My attempts so far are not worth the CPU-time of SO...

**Update:** It actually works now, using:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+\.pdf)$  /files/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: We'd still like to look at those attempts you made so as to inform you about the shortcomings.

Comment: The htaccess is in root folder? You're accessing the files as `http://host/523523624/aboutus.pdf`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.